# Streaming gzipped file to S3 via AWS SDK GO

Tags: go, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-sdk

I followed the example on the AWS site for gzipping files and streaming them to S3, found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/latest/v1/developerguide/common-examples.title.html

I am having an issue where the only thing landing in my S3 bucket are files with basically just the GZIP headers. Every single file is 23b in size.

Any idea what would cause this?

My code:

```
func (t *Table) Upload() {
  year := time.Now().Format("2006")
  month := time.Now().Format("01")
  day := time.Now().Format("02")
  reader, writer := io.Pipe()
  go func() {
    gw := gzip.NewWriter(writer)
    io.Copy(gw, t.File)
    t.File.Close()
    gw.Close()
    writer.Close()
  }()
  uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_REGION"))}))
  result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Body:   reader,
    Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_BUCKET")),
    Key:    aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s/%s/%s", os.Getenv("S3_KEY"), year, month, day, t.Name+".csv.gz")),
  })
  if err != nil {
    log.WithField("error", err).Fatal("Failed to upload file.")
  }
  log.WithField("location", result.Location).Info("Successfully uploaded to")
}
```

Comment: what is t.File, is it open? io.Copy copies until EOF or error. You should be checking the return values of io.Copy for bytes written and errors.

Comment: t (or Table) is a struct that has an open pointer to File

Comment: I did update io.Copy to:
    _, err := io.Copy(gw, t.File)
just to check for errors and there are none.

Comment: have you ever encountered performance issue with this approach? to me it seems quite slow

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that even though you may have a struct designed as such (as I do):

```
type Table struct {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Name     string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Path     string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  FileName string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File     *os.File                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Buffer   *bufio.Writer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Data     chan string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

using a function that requires a pointer to that struct does not necessarily leave the Table.File in an open state.

I made sure the file was closed when writing to it was complete and reopened it inside my upload function. This resolved the issue and uploaded the full gzipped file to S3.

Thanks for the heads up on the possible issue @jrwren

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `t.File.Write()` in other code?  If you do， the cursor of `t.File` could be the end of file. So you should seek the file cursor to the origin of file.

Call  `t.File.Seek(0,0)`   before `io.Copy(gw,t.File)` (line 9)